# Colocar um ícone ao invês de uma string HTML

Tags: html, angular

Tenho o seguinte código:

`<a (click)="verificarSeEscondeSaldo()"> {{ escondeSaldo ? 'Exibir' : 'Ocultar'}}</a>`

O treecho faz corretamente o que eu desejo, porém, ao invés do texto: 'exibir' ou 'ocultar' eu gostaria de colocar um ícone.

Alguém pode ajudar como fazer??

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Utilizando ícones da biblioteca **fontawesome** por exemplo, pode inserir os ícones em uma tag `i` e ir trocando as classes do ícones através da condição.

Answer (score 0):

Então, basta seguir a mesma lógica que você já implementou, mas dentro do icone.

```
<a (click)="verificarSeEscondeSaldo()">
  <mat-icon>
    {{ escondeSaldo ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'}}
  </mat-icon>
</a>
```

**Seu Modulo**

```
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon/typings/icon-module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CoreModule } from './core';
import { HelloFrameworkModule } from './hello-framework';

@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [CoreModule, MatIconModule]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Utilize o mat-icon do Angular Material;

Se você não tiver instalado,  `ng add @angular/material`